# hibernate ListIn query returning same item two times

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am searching foods by category. A food model can has more than one category. When i tried to get food by giving category list if it includes 2 categories,  it's returning 2 times same food.

it's my query:

```
findAllByCategoryListInAndDeletedFalseAndFoodNameContaining(search.getCategories(), search.getValue())
```

and here is my Food Model:

```
public class Food extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Category> categoryList; }
```

category model:

```
public class Category extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
          private String name;
          @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
          @OneToOne
          private FileModel categoryImage;
```

}

Comment: If you are sure you don't have duplicates in your db then use spring-boot configuration `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to print the SQL which is executed to better understand what your query realy does.

Comment: thanks, i willl try

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved this problem but i think it shouldn't solve with this method.

```
 List<Food> foodList = foodRepo.
            findAllByCategoryListInAndDeletedFalseAndFoodNameContaining(search.getCategories(), search.getValue());

foodList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```